# jQuery click function only work once when trying to animate using Textillate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to animate text using jQuery and [Textillate.js](http://jschr.github.io/textillate/) but it only works once using `.click()`; it needs to refresh the browser to animate the text when click. I hope someone can help.

My HTML:

```
<h1 class="test">Im so handome!</h1>
```

And this is the JavaScript

```
var asdf = $('.test');
asdf.click(function() {
    asdf.textillate({
        in: {
            effect: 'bounceIn'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: From what I can see, there's just an animation for `in`, and that will probably not work on clicks after it's done.

Comment: Have you tried defining a out animation?

Comment: Do you want continuously bouncing In?

Comment: i just tried the out animation but still nothing change. i only want to re animate again when i click the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should init the `textillate` plugin outside of click function, and then trigger the api within the click function.

This should work:

```
var asdf = $('.test');
asdf.textillate({
    autoStart: false,
    in: {
        effect: 'bounceIn'
    }
  });
var api = asdf.data('textillate');

asdf.click(function() {
  api.start();
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `asdf.textillate('start')` without needing to save off the data object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var asdf = $('.test');
asdf.click(function() {
   setInterval(function(){
   asdf.textillate({
    in: {
        effect: 'bounceIn'
    }}, 200); 
  });
});
```

200 is to animate after each 200 milisec.